# Отменить правило для другой директории в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

В корне самописного сайта в .htaccess стоят правила

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+).asp$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В корне есть директория support, в которую хочу поставить другую cms, но по адресу site.ru/support/ выдаётся ошибка HTTP ERROR 500

В новой cms стоят такие правила

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html(\?.*)?$ index.php?html=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Подскажите, как быть, как переопределить правила и можно ли вообще?

Comment: 1. Начните наконец-то использовать nginx вместо apache - поверьте, централизованные конфиги это сильно лучше, чем путаница с htaccess

Comment: 2.  Поставьте правило вида в начало: `RewriteRule ^(support)($|/) - [L]` напоминаю, что правила смотрятся сверху вниз и выигрывает первое подходящее